# Sequential/continuous/continued/parallel addition

Tags: mathematics

I would like to know what's the standard way to say **sequential/continuous/continued/parallel** multiplication or addition for calculation like `3 * 5 * 10 * 2 * 11` and `1 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 4 + 100`.

PS: Glad that this question attracts some attention. I asked because in Chinese there are effectively specific names: `连加` and `连乘` where `连` means [this](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS776US776&q=translation+%E8%BF%9E+english&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKxZvS7urvAhVG_7sIHWLFBa4Q7xYoAHoECAEQMA&biw=1920&bih=978), `加` means addition and `乘` means mutiplication.

Comment: The sum of a sequence is called a 'series', usually referring to the (a + b + c + ...) form rather than the actual total. But sequences are patterned rather than being repeated addition operations with arbitrary terms.

Comment: I’m sure this is a better fit on Mathematics.SE.

Comment: [correction: I would like to know the standard way to say: blah blah blah]

Comment: @lambie there is no rule telling you that you have to use a colon after the object, and you told me that this is not the point, yet you do add one; why not write "I would like to know the standard way to say blah blah blah"?

Comment: @LPH I was not correcting the colon: I was correcting the **grammar**. Did you miss the grammar?

Comment: @Lambie Your form is probably preferable; as far as style goes it is, but the grammar is not wrong. Nevertheless, that is not the point: I can't see why you add the second colon since "blah blah blah" is again the object.

Comment: As in some answers and comments, these are merely *sums* and *products*. Other commentary, no matter how interesting, is of little relevance. It is of no use to introduce the idea of a series unless there is a generative expression for the series, and no such generative expression is given. Because the terms in the sums and products commute, their order does not matter, and that too removes any point to talking of a series. I have voted to move it to maths but had the commentary not unfortunately shifted discussion to secondary mathematical matters it should have remained in this site.

Comment: @Lambie If you want to be a pedant, at least be an accurate pedant. Except in scripts of plays etc, your use of a "segmental colon" to mark the start of speech is obsolete. Most of the references on the Web appear to be copied from Wikipedia, which gives a source to the usage but doesn't mention that the source was written 115 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Such calculations don't have a specific name. They are merely products or sums (respectively). The answers which suggest, for example, that you refer to the sum as a series are incorrect, as the relevant feature to create a series appears to be missing. You would need to identify a relationship between elements of the series, specifically a way to calculate each successive element, and the sequence of values (typically integers) over which to perform the calculation.

To be clear, it's not that it's impossible to create such a calculation, it's that you've not provided the relationships, and one is not readily apparent. There may be a function, the sequence of which would result in the elements of your sum or product. But it's not given, and it's not obvious.

Comment: You do not have to provide a rule of calculation of the terms; all you need is a function and any function with a finite domain and range such as those involved here can be specified by the set of its ordered pairs. For instance: f(1)=1, f(2)=5, f(3)=3, f(4)=2, f(5)=4, f(6)=100; then ∑f(x) is a defined finite sum (we don't say "series" usually, although it is possible. On the contrary, the function **is** obvious. I agree with you, however,  on this  point: terms such  as "iterated sum"  are not used often (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182704/a-question-on-iterated-sums).

Answer (score 2):

From this [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Notation_and_terminology), where the symbol "∑" is said to represent an *iteration*, you could call expressions such as "1 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 4 + 100"  ***iterated sums*** (similarly for products).

You can also speak of  ***repeated sums*** ([Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_binary_operation#Notation)) (similarly for products).

Comment: I believe this answer isn't correct. The idea behind iterated elements for such sums is that one is able to identify a function which creates successive elements. No such function is provided here, nor is one apparent.

Comment: Even if there exists some function *f* that generates 1, 5, 3, 2, 4, and 100, describing their sum as an "iterated sum" lacks clarity. ∑f(x) represents a sum of iterations of f(x). "Iterated sum" better describes an operation of the form ∑∑f(.) where the sum itself is being iterated.

Comment: @DerrellDurrett There is always an index set and in fact any set of the same cardinal as the set of terms of the sum  paired with 1, 2, 3, …will do, the simplest being a segment of the natural numbers starting at 0 or 1; but you can use any set and construct a function. There exists in fact  an infinity of functions having the range  {1,5,3,2,4,100}; it is only needed to choose as domains (which will be the index sets) the sets {1,2,3,4,5,6}, {2,3,4,5,6,7},{3,4,5,6,7,8}, etc. They can all be an index set for the sum "1 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 4 + 100".

Comment: @max norton    Your specialization to sums of sums is probably  not a general practice. Here is what Wikipedia says of _iterated binary operations_: "In mathematics, an iterated binary operation is an extension of a binary operation on a set S to a function on finite sequences of elements of S through repeated application. Common examples include the extension of the addition operation to the summation operation, and the extension of the multiplication operation to the product operation.

Comment: @LPH But the sentences you have cited also imply that *summation* can be defined as *iterated addition*, with the result that *iterated summation* is either redundant or means the iteration of the summation operation. The [math stack exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182704/a-question-on-iterated-sums) you linked to in a different comment uses "iterated sums" in the way I'm suggesting, to refer to ∑∑f(.).

Comment: @maxnorton "In mathematics, summation is the addition of a sequence of any kind of numbers" (wikipedia).  ∑ᵢ∑ⱼf(xᵢⱼ) = ∑ᵢ (f(xᵢ₁) + f(xᵢ₂) + …+f(xᵢⱼ) + …). For each i, ∑ⱼf(xᵢⱼ) is the summation of the f(xᵢⱼ) over the index set J and ∑ᵢ∑ⱼf(xᵢⱼ) is the summation of the ∑ⱼf(xᵢⱼ) over the index set I; (∑ⱼf(xᵢⱼ))(i ∈ I) is a sequence of number the terms of which are in the form of sums; "summation" is a term you apply to any sums, no matter what the form of the terms, and in fact, these terms may even be products; all that matters:  the expression stands for a number, anything that you can add.

Comment: @LPH I don't dispute anything in your last comment. Building on it, if "∑ⱼf(xᵢⱼ) is the summation of the f(xᵢⱼ) over the index set J," and {f(xᵢⱼ)}(j ∈ J) = {1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 100} , what is gained by calling ∑ⱼf(xᵢⱼ) an *iterated* sum instead of just a sum?

Comment: @maxnorton That is the point: when dealing with symbolic forms mathematicians do not bother to carry that precision and speak of sums; they may add "finite" when the sequence is finite;  when they are infinite they talk more often of infinite series or, for short, series. As they manipulate symbols but rarely numbers, except in applications,  they do not use "iterated" very much. However, especially for the purpose of more elementary  contexts, this term can be used  so as to have a name a little more specific, as after all "a+b" is also a sum (it could not be called iterated).

Answer (score 2):

These are just sums and products, both of which are neutral with respect to the number of elements they operate on. (Reference: The first definition of sum in the American Heritage Dictionary, 5th ed. is, "An amount obtained as a result of adding numbers.")

One plain-language option that hasn't been raised is that if you have a word to describe the set of numbers you're operating on, then you can talk about the *sum of all* or *product of all* elements in the set, e.g.,

> The sum of all the passengers' weights should not exceed the elevator's weight capacity.